# How to get 'executionId' in Google Cloud Functions when the function fails?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I need to fetch logs after Cloud Function execution, but the problem is that when execution fails, the result does not contain 'executionId', although I can see the logs in the cloud console. 
The code is:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

service = build('cloudfunctions', 'v1', credentials=service_credentials)

result = service.projects().locations().functions().call(
    name=function_name,
    body=request_body,
).execute()
```

On successful execution, it contains 'executionId' and  'result', but if it fails it only contains 'error', so I can't fetch the logs for this execution.

Comment: did you find a solution for this ? We are struggling with the same issue.

Comment: @FreskMike
no, I solved the issue by using micro-VM inside a function and switching to HTTP interface (the quota on direct API calls is quite small).

Comment: @taras: Can you explain how you did it?

Comment: @praneeth-peiris you basically make a cloud function an [http-function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http). Then you can apply any auth scheme for it if you need. And yes, this is a workaround.

Comment: I tried to invoke a Cloud Function as an HTTP endpoint, but the response doesn't return an execution ID when the function fails. That's my issue. If you have a code snippet, or the steps, would be amazing!

Comment: Got it. So I used https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2.
You run your function inside VM and put handlers on errors, console.log, etc. Then in the end you just output the structure with all those values captured, along with anything else you need. So you end up not needing executionId, and all the data you need is in the response.